# Angularjs display date format from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, html

I have a json with the field date like this :  "DataIscr": "1969-6-17T00:00:00+01:00"
and I make a filter for DataIscr:
`<label for="DataIscr">DataIscr:</label>
<select style="width:200px" data-ng-options="Person.DataIscr as Person.DataIscr for Person in OutAnagrafica" id="DataIscr" data-ng-model="filter.DataIscr" class="form-control input-sm"></select>`

but I want to display only the year. How can I use the formatter?? 
Plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/ED1v7czBosNSpCYxKW7n?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your comprehension should use the date filter:

```
Person.DataIscr as Person.DataIscr | date:'yyyy' for Person in OutAnagrafica
```

However, your dates are not well. Review the format.

```
1969-12-2T00:00:00+01:00 -> 1969-12-02T00:00:00+01:00
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! My mistake! But there's a way to filter the objects having the same year?? I have tried filter "unique" from ui-utils but there's still duplicate.

Comment: @sidos In that case is best to use a function as the data source of your comprehension. And fire another function when the selection changes.